# How to strip out \\" and \\"" from json_encode() in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple question:

My JSON contains the following and I'm stripping down from 4500 lines to a few to make a point:

```
{ "status": 200, "statusText": "Success", "result": [ { "id": 44281, "title": "100% Sankey by Richard Kaufman - Book", "qty": 11, "price": "42.0000" }, { "id": 47809, "title": "10 Exact Cuts (BLUE) Henry Evans", "qty": 4, "price": "45.0000" }, { "id": 37650, "title": "10 Exact Cuts (RED) Henry Evans", "qty": 12, "price": "45.0000" }, 

...
```

to here where the problems begin

```
      {
         "id":50104,
         "title":"System 6 - 6 by Six by Michael \\""Six\\"" Muldoon",
         "qty":5,
         "price":"30.0000"
      },
      {
         "id":67993,
         "title":"Acro Index Dry Erase 3\\"X5\\" (Online Instructions) by Blake Vogt - Trick",
         "qty":17,
         "price":"49.9500"
      },
      {
         "id":70741,
         "title":"Acro Index Dry Erase Large 5\\"x8\\"(Online Instructions) by Blake Vogt - Trick",
         "qty":113,
         "price":"99.9500"
      },
   ]
}
```

OK, as you can see the ONLY issues I'm having is STRIPPING out the \\" and \\"" from my JSON which I'm doing using:

```
    if (!empty($result->items->InventoryItem)) {
        // echo "Items added between " . str_replace('T', ' ', $starttime) . " and " . str_replace('T', ' ', $endtime) . "<p></p><ul>";
        foreach ($result->items->InventoryItem as $item) {
            // echo "<li><a href='https://www.somedomain.com/product.aspx?id=" . $item->InternalId . "' target='_blank'>$item->Title</a></li>";
            
            $id = $item->InternalId;
            $title = $item->Title;
            $qty = $item->QuantityAvailable;
            $price = $item->SuggestedRetailPrice;

            // get rid of \\" and then \\""

            $title = str_replace('5\\"x8\\"', '5x8', $title);
            $title = str_replace('\\\\""Six\\\\""', 'Six', $title);
            $title = str_replace('3\\\\"X5\\\\"', '3x5', $title);
            
            stripslashes($title);
            
            $return_arr[] = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "title" => $title,
                "qty" => $qty,
                "price" => $price
            );

        }

        $return_obj = array (
            "status" => 200,
            "statusText" => "Success",
            "result" => $return_arr
        );

        // echo "</ul>";
        echo var_export(json_encode($return_obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

    } else {
        echo "No items found";
    }
```

The above JSON is what I'm getting back and putting into JSONFormatter online.
[image: Formatting problems with escape characters]

I really want to replace \\""Six\\"" with 'Six', 3\\"X5\\" with 3"x5" or just 3x5, and 5\\"x8\\" with 5x8 or 5"x8" because I don't need escape characters. I know I can do it in JavaScript but why, when PHP is my heavy lifter.

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**
Here's what works PERFECTLY with help from everyone below. THANK YOU.

```
    if (!empty($result->items->InventoryItem)) {
        // echo "Items added between " . str_replace('T', ' ', $starttime) . " and " . str_replace('T', ' ', $endtime) . "<p></p><ul>";
        foreach ($result->items->InventoryItem as $item) {
            // echo "<li><a href='https://www.murphysmagic.com/product.aspx?id=" . $item->InternalId . "' target='_blank'>$item->Title</a></li>";
            
            $id = $item->InternalId;
            $title = $item->Title;
            $qty = $item->QuantityAvailable;
            $price = $item->SuggestedRetailPrice;

            // get rid of \\" and then \\""

            $title = str_replace('5\\"x8\\"', '5x8', $title);
            $title = str_replace('\\\\""Six\\\\""', 'Six', $title);
            $title = str_replace('3\\\\"X5\\\\"', '3x5', $title);
            
            stripslashes($title);
            
            $return_arr[] = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "title" => $title,
                "qty" => $qty,
                "price" => $price
            );

        }
        **// UPDATED to reflect what's below.**
        $return_arr[] = array(
            "status" => 200,
            "statusText" => "Success",
            [
                "result" => $return_arr
            ]
        );

        // echo "</ul>";
        echo json_encode($return_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    } else {
        echo "No items found";
    }
```

**SECOND UPDATE: and quickie!**

So, my JSON is coming back but, as you can see, I want the STATUS and STATUSTEXT at the top BEFORE the result [0-99] not like you see it here.

Here's the updated ARRAY in PHP here for clarity:

```
        **// UPDATED to reflect what's below.**
        $return_arr[] = array(
            "status" => 200,
            "statusText" => "Success",
            [
                "result" => $return_arr
            ]
        );
```

**LAST AND FINAL SOLUTION UPDATE**

I GOT IT!

```
        $obj = (object) [
            "status" => 200,
            "statusText" => "Success",
            "result" => $return_arr
        ];

       echo json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[image: JSON coming into the JS file for AJAX]

Comment: JSON is a string, that's why it's shown with quotes. When you parse it (`JSON.parse()` in JavaScript, `json_decode()` in PHP), it will be converted to an object or array, and the escaped characters will be parsed properly. You don't need to do anything about the slashes, this is all handled by the JSON parser.

Comment: So this: echo var_export(json_encode($return_obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); should be echo var_export(json_decode($return_obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); correct?

Comment: I believe your issue is an additional unneeded layer of encoding. `echo json_encode(...)` should be all you do; `var_export` is messing up your valid JSON.

Comment: 100% you are overworking this. You don't need any of this.

Comment: THIS echo var_export(json_decode($return_obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); creates an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR on my debug console.

Comment: Of course it does. `$return_obj` is not a JSON string, you can't decode it.

Comment: `json_encode` is object/array => string. `json_decode` is string => object/array.

Comment: So, removing the json_encode does this

array ( 'status' => 200, 'statusText' => 'Success', 'result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 44281, 'title' => '100% Sankey by Richard Kaufman - Book', 'qty' => 11, 'price' => '42.0000', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => 47809, 'title' => '10 Exact Cuts (BLUE) Henry Evans', 'qty' => 4, 'price' => '45.0000', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => 37650, 'title' => '10 Exact Cuts (RED) Henry Evans', 'qty' => 12, 'price' => '45.0000', ), 3 =>

Comment: I would remove var_export, json decode is a string that you can show up.

Comment: That's NOT JSON and NOT what I want coming back from PHP

Comment: The problem you're running into is that `var_export()` shows you how you would write the JSON as a PHP string literal. That requires an extra level of escaping to get all the internal quotes and backslashes that are used in JSON. So you're encoding twice: Once for JSON, and once for PHP.

Comment: If you want JSON coming from PHP, just do `echo json_encode($return_obj);`

Comment: Barmar, you and I and everyone did it. I posted an UPDATE. Thank you.  Send in my solution with your comments and I'll accept. THANK YOU EVERYONE! TEAM WORK!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
    if (!empty($result->items->InventoryItem)) {
        // echo "Items added between " . str_replace('T', ' ', $starttime) . " and " . str_replace('T', ' ', $endtime) . "<p></p><ul>";
        foreach ($result->items->InventoryItem as $item) {
            // echo "<li><a href='https://www.somedomain.com/product.aspx?id=" . $item->InternalId . "' target='_blank'>$item->Title</a></li>";

            $id = $item->InternalId;
            $title = $item->Title;
            $qty = $item->QuantityAvailable;
            $price = $item->SuggestedRetailPrice;

            // get rid of \\" and then \\""

            $title = str_replace('5\\"x8\\"', '5x8', $title);
            $title = str_replace('\\\\""Six\\\\""', 'Six', $title);
            $title = str_replace('3\\\\"X5\\\\"', '3x5', $title);

            stripslashes($title);

            $return_arr[] = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "title" => $title,
                "qty" => $qty,
                "price" => $price
            );
        }
        **// THIS DID IT!**
        $obj = (object) [
            "status" => 200,
            "statusText" => "Success",
            "result" => $return_arr
        ];

        echo json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        echo "No items found";
    }
```

and here's what the result looks like

[image]